# Cakephp auth: Binding error messages to scope condition

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

Is there a way to bind an auth error message to the scope condition of the auth component?

For instance say I have:

```
'Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Blowfish' => array('scope' => array('User.activated' => 1))));
```

I would like set an error if the scope condition fails. I need to be able to differentiate that from the error that is presented if the user/pass is incorrect.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when you manually log users in using `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User']);`. There maybe a return object or exception you can intercept before the view is rendered.

Comment: That method returns a boolean unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, I've had a root around CakePHP's source code and I've come to the conclusion that it doesn't do anything fancy when using scoped conditions, it simply appends them as additional query conditions. It will either find the user which matches the username/password combination and any scope conditions, or it doesn't.

One possible solution would be to manually log users in and check for the activated field like so:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login($this->data['User'])) {
            // check activated field
            if ($this->Auth->user('activated') == 1) {
                // user is activated
                $this->redirect(...);
            } else {
                // user is not activated
                // log the user out
                $this->Auth->logout();
                // redirect to an error page for inactive users
                $this->redirect(..);
            }
        }
        // redirect to an error page for wrong username/password
        $this->redirect(..);
    }
}
```

I should clarify that you should not specify scope conditions in configuring the authentication component.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I thought when I looked at the source. Wasn't sure if there was some other method of doing this. It would be a worthwhile addition to cake I think to allow such binding. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Your welcome @BIOS. I definitely support your use case here because I feel you're loosing information about the authentication process which could influence how your application responds. The difficulty with implementing such a function is supporting backwards compatibility and the whole _convention over configuration_ ethos that CakePHP has. If you feel you have a strong enough case then I recommend you post on their [issue tracker](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard) or implement it yourself and make a pull request on their [repo](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pulls)

Comment: I think that if you have to avoid using the 'conditions' functionality in a valid use case, then the functionality is patently broken. It would be better if the login method returned an object containing all auth failures rather than just false. Backwards compatibility would of course be an issue. Will consider a ticket. Thanks again.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check the special parameters prior to calling the Auth login component? For example: `if($this->User->customCheck()){$this->Auth->login();} else{ _Something other than logging them in._ }`

Comment: @JadedCore It would make sense to yes but because this is a security system, it's probably best to reveal as little information about the internal state of the system as possible. If we followed your suggestion, a non-user could probe for activated accounts based on the feedback returned by the site.